# How to make mariadb 10 make full use of a multi-core processor?

Tags: multithreading, cpu, mariadb

I'm using mariadb 10,in the official document only mentioned the 5.x version.I tried using **thread_pool_min_threads** but didn't work at all,It only shutdown and left a message said "Unknown variable" in the event log.

Answer (score 0):

You did  not mention your platform. thread_pool_min_threads does not exist on Unix variations (as also pointed out in the [official document](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/threadpool-in-55/)). It is Windows-only variable.
If I list threadpool related variables on 10.0.3, on Windows, I get

```
mysql> show variables like 'thread_po%';
+-------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name           | Value |
+-------------------------+-------+
| thread_pool_max_threads | 500   |
| thread_pool_min_threads | 1     |
+-------------------------+-------+
```